# App Engine gives error in number formatting when deployed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, encoding

I have just deployed my app and as soon as I go on the homepage I get the '500 internal server error' page. Having looked through the logs I got the following error:

> type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file /base/data/home/apps/spare-wheels/1.348259065130939449/sparewheels.py on line 465, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details (sparewheels.py, line 465)

The line in question looks like this:

```
self.template_values['price_pounds'] = "£%.2f" % (float(self.event.price_pence)/100)
```

This worked fine when running on localhost: is there something about number formatting that the Google Apps version of Python doesn't support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the encoding of the python file, is it UTF-8? That error message suggests you may have saved the file as an ASCII format with international characters in the file (aka "£") causing Google's python runtime to barf up that 500 error.

Also try tossing this line on the first or second line of the python file:

```
# coding=utf-8
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to muck with file encodings as @Shakakai suggests, and that's the only non-ASCII character you're dealing with in your source, you could also just replace that character with the equivalent HTML entity `&pound;`, which will render out correctly.